# Power Consumption and efficiency

Tags: efficiency, power-consumption, atmega328p

I know that similar threads had been answered but due to the fact that i am a beginner at electronics i would like to verify my measurements concerning about voltage total current and power consumption of my circuit.As you see i use an Atmega 328p microcontroller and some sensors such as Dht22(digital temperature-humidity),lm35(analog temperature)Soil Humidity(classic arduino analog sensor from adafruit).Below its my schema https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Bfq.jpg and a table of my results https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ssM6.jpg

1st Question:According to these measurements my calculations are right?

Total Current 26.8mA

Total Power=26.8mA * 12V=321mW

8battery pack AA Alkaline 2600mAh

Battery Lasts=2600mAh/26.8mA = 97Hours

2nd Question:Concerning efficiency will be better if i have a 9V power supply or a different perspective of my circuit and how i measure this in theory with numbers.

Any suggestions to my circuit and my measurements will be great!

Comment: My little brother would unscrew light bulbs to save energy.   those little chandelier bulbs?   those he would unscrew.   To save money.

Comment: @G-V: Don't try to make any sense of the above comment. It's nonsense.

Comment: Haha its ok.For me its about knowledge because now i am trying to learn about electronics and not just type some codes at arduino ide.However i still laugh lol.

Comment: I would like to compliment the question.  Many times, beginners drop in without 10% of the thought that you put into the question.  Bravo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick scan through your figures and they seem good.

Note that your 7805 regulator is dropping 7 V and the circuit is using 5 V. That means that 7/12 of your power is being dissipated as heat in the 7805. You can reduce this in a number of ways.

- Reduce your battery voltage to 5 AA cells. The 7.5 V will be enough to power your circuit but you won't be able to drain your batteries as far before the voltage regulation starts to deteriorate. Your 9 V solution would be safer.
- Use a buck-type voltage regulator. This will be much more efficient than the 7805 linear regulator and will work over a wide input range.
- Do both the above.